# Facebook app redirection : I do have the permissions but i keep gettin empty $session

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

*index.php*

```
     require_once ('../src/facebook.php');
     $facebook = new Facebook(array(
     'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'cookie' => true,
    ));
    $session = $facebook->getSession();
    if (!empty($session)) {
try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $user = $facebook->api('/me');
    echo 'session found';
        } catch (Exception $e) {}
    if(!empty($user)) {
        include 'result.php';
                }

            else {
                    $url = $facebook->GetLoginUrl(array('canvas' => 1,
                                   'fbconnect' => 0,
                                   'req_perms' => 'publish_stream, email, user_birthday, user_hometown, user_location, user_religion_politics, user_relationships, friends_about_me, friends_relationships',
                                   'next' => 'http://www.applicationsite.com/index.php',
                                   'cancel_url' => $appCanvasPage ));
                  #echo 'no user -> link to login';
    echo '<a href="'.$url.'">Click here to install the app</a>;
        }
    }
    else {
            $url = $facebook->GetLoginUrl(array('canvas' => 1,
                                   'fbconnect' => 0,
                                   'req_perms' => 'publish_stream, email, user_birthday, user_hometown, user_location, user_religion_politics, user_relationships, friends_about_me, friends_relationships',
                                   'next' =>'http://www.applicationsite.com/index.php',
                                   'cancel_url' => $appCanvasPage ));
   #echo 'no session -> link to login';
    echo '<a href="'.$url.'">Click here to install the app</a>;
           }
       ?>
```

*choice.php*

```
    just to html links to :

    http://www.applicationsite.com/index.php?&param=1
    http://www.applicationsite.com/index.php?&param=1
```

*result.php*

```
        <?php 


        extract($_GET);

        if (isset($param)){

        I show my result

        }
        else
        {
        include 'choice.php';   
        }

    ?>
```

When i first launch the page, i get the "no session" link, so i click and im asked to provide permissions, once i click on "allow", it redirects me to the "choice.php" page, wich means the $params isnt set. thats great.

But when i click on it, i'm back to the index page with the "no session" link, and i have to click on the link again, and then it gets me back to the "choice.php" page. and i keep turning round.

Comment: what browser are you using? if you are using IE then you need to put p3p header otherwise you wont go far

Comment: Nope, i'm using firefox and chrome ans test browser.

Comment: Have you tried without the extract() function, ie if(isset($_GET['param']))

Comment: I do receive the param im trying to give wth "param=" but i dont have the $session variable.

Answer (score 0):

check this one ... I moved the if !empty(user) to the bottom of the page and use if $user... if this wont work then I will give up ^^

`require_once ('../src/facebook.php');
     $facebook = new Facebook(array(
     'appId' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'cookie' => true,
    ));
    $session = $facebook->getSession();
    if (!empty($session)) {
try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $user = $facebook->api('/me');
    echo 'session found';
        } catch (Exception $e) {}
    }
    else {
            $url = $facebook->GetLoginUrl(array('canvas' => 1,
                                   'fbconnect' => 0,
                                   'req_perms' => 'publish_stream, email, user_birthday, user_hometown, user_location, user_religion_politics, user_relationships, friends_about_me, friends_relationships',
                                   'next' =>'http://www.applicationsite.com/index.php',
                                   'cancel_url' => $appCanvasPage ));
   #echo 'no session -> link to login';
    echo '<a href="'.$url.'">Click here to install the app</a>';
           }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>

    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
   <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <?php if ($user){ ?>

        <!-- whatever you want to put on the website just for user goes here-->
     <div class="whatever">
        <?php include "result.php";?>
     </div>
    <?php } ?>
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: Once i login, i get the session, and i can do operations in FQL in the page following the authorization. The problems comes after, when I click on a new link. There it seems i lost the authorization.

Comment: if you have the code in fbmain.php or whatever... in the next file (where the link redirects) you will have to include fbmain.php and facebook.php libraries ... I include facebook.php and fbmain.php on every site on my canvas app, even if its a link only .. check it out..

Comment: well as you can see, the whole thing happen in index.php, and i only do some includes in it. links reload the same page with some more parameters.

Comment: I fount the reason.. I think... You are missing ' in the line ... ehh I will edit my answer and check the end

Comment: there I have found another missing ' ... at the last echo statement after</a> should be '  as well so add it and check  ;)

Comment: Thanks. this was just a type mistake. got it in my real code. Pb still remains

Comment: hmmm can you show what code is in choice? is it only header("Location: http://www.blabla.com/bla.com?&param=1"); ?

Comment: here is my choice.php

   ' <div align="center">
    <img src="background.png" width="500" height="300" border="0" usemap="#Map" />
    <map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="27,129,215,252" href="http://www.example.com/index.php?&param=1" alt="1" />
    <area shape="rect" coords="282,128,464,251" href="http://www.example.com/index.php?&param=2" alt="2" />
    </map>
    </div>'
Note that choice is included in result.php (if param is not set), which itself included in index.php (if session and user is set)

Comment: Sorry about the formating, it doesnt allow me to post answer.

Comment: Try to use the new code man. I didn't test it but it should work now.. if it wont work then it's over my skills... remember to add <?php at the begining of the code, for some reason it doesn't show when i pasted my code

Comment: Nope its not a coding problem but thank you. Its more of an Oauth and token problem i guess